# Percentile If Statement Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, percentile

I have a table that has two columns and looks like the one below. My goal is to create a third column wherein the output is the percentile ranking of that line's growth rate segmented by group. That is, I want the formula to only look at the growth rates of 'Black" groups and give me the percentile ranking for the growth rate 10%.

Can't figure this out for the life of me.

```
Group        Growth
Black         10%
Black         -1%
Blue           0%
Blue           5%
Blue           5%
Red            2%
Green          2%
Green          9%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in cell C2:

```
=IF($A$2:$A$9=A3,$B$2:$B$9,0)
```

But make sure you press ctrl-shift-enter instead of hitting enter.
Then copy this down to C9.

This will give you 9%, 9%, 10%, 10%, 10%, 2%, 11%, 11%.

What this does is sum up everything that's black, blue, red, green, respectively.  Adjust for your growth rate formula as necessary.

Comment: This formula is returning the values in column B only--even when pressing ctrl-shift-enter. So instead of 9%, 9% for rows 2 and 3, I am getting 10%, -1%.

Also, the growth rate is hard-entered--not a formula. How can I get column C to show the percentile ranking for each rate relative to all rates within that grouping (e.g. 'Black')?

Comment: Actually--I see what I did. The formula does work but its not clear to me what its doing. I should also mention that there are no growth rates (null values) for some rows within the table, though a group name (e.g. 'Black') is listed for that row.

Comment: it's only adding up all the blacks for the black rows.  so (10%) + (-1%) for all rows that say Black.  I'm just using it as an example, but you have to adjust it for your "growth rate".